# Continuous function, monotonic converging sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, definition

In our lecture notes our lecturer wrote

"f is continuous iff f(x<sub>n</sub>) →  f(x) for all x<sub>n</sub>→ x strictly monotone."

I was wondering...the definition is fine even if I don't restrict myself to strictly monotonic sequences, right?

Comment: Yes, you can either do this restriction or leave it away, it's equivalent for continuity in $\mathbb{R}$.